# Laravel Blade: extend multiple views and adding more content

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following scenario: a view that shows some data (let's call it "cars"), another view that shows some other data (let's call it "motorbikes") and a view that must show the data of "cars" and "motorbikes" in addition of some extra content (let's call it "vehicles"). **The three views have sense by themselves and can be shown separatelly.**

The problem is that I can't find the way to build the "vehicles" view **without repeating code** because I don't know how to use Laravel's Blade templating in order to **extend multiple views ('cars' and 'motorbikes') and add more content**. Each view is divided into three sections ('styles', 'scripts' and 'content') because the HTML content of each view needs specific CSS and JS files.

**layouts/master.blade.php (simplified version)**

```
<html>
<head>
    @yield('styles')
    @yield('scripts')
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

**cars.blade.php (simplified version)**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('styles')
    [CSS files required by the HTML content that shows cars]
@stop
@section('scripts')
    [JS files required by the HTML content that shows cars]
@stop
@section('content')
    [HTML content that shows cars]
@stop
```

**motorbikes.blade.php (simplified version)**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('styles')
    [CSS files required by the HTML content that shows motorbikes]
@stop
@section('scripts')
    [JS files required by the HTML content that shows motorbikes]
@stop
@section('content')
    [HTML content that shows motorbikes]
@stop
```

**vehicles.blade.php (simplified version)**

```
@extends('?') <!-- It should extend 'cars' and 'motorbikes' -->

@section('styles')
    @parent <!-- It should refer to the content of 'cars' and 'motorbikes' -->
    [CSS files required by the HTML content that shows aditional info about vehicles]
@stop
@section('scripts')
    @parent <!-- It should refer to the content of 'cars' and 'motorbikes' -->
    [JS files required by the HTML content that shows aditional info about vehicles]
@stop
@section('content')
    @parent <!-- It should refer to the content of 'cars' and 'motorbikes' -->
    [HTML content that shows aditional info about vehicles]
@stop
```

### **Undesirable approach**

I have already thought about splitting the view 'cars' and the view 'motorbikes' into separated files like:

```
cars/styles.blade.php
cars/scripts.blade.php
cars/content.blade.php
motorbikes/styles.blade.php
motorbikes/scripts.blade.php
motorbikes/content.blade.php
```

Then I could build vehicles.blade.php like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('styles')
    @include('cars.styles')
    @include('motorbikes.styles')
    [CSS files required by the HTML content that shows aditional info about vehicles]
@stop
@section('scripts')
    @include('cars.scripts')
    @include('motorbikes.scripts')
    [JS files required by the HTML content that shows aditional info about vehicles]
@stop
@section('content')
    @include('cars.content')
    @include('motorbikes.content')
    [HTML content that shows aditional info about vehicles]
@stop
```

But I want to avoid this kind of splitting because, in fact, I have many more views than just 'cars' and 'motorbikes' and I find undesirable to multiply the number of files by three.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson Laravel 5.4

Comment: Can you explain a little more or give an example of what you'll be using from `cars` or `motorbikes` in your `vehicles` file?

Comment: @RossWilson For example, `cars` shows a list of car models and `motorbikes` shows a list of motorbike models. Each list (HTML) has its own CSS (styles) and JS (for some actions) files. That means that there are CSS and JS files for `cars` and CSS and JS files for `motorbikes`. The view `vehicles` must include those CSS and JS files of `cars` and `motorbikes` and **add more HTML content and CSS and JS files (adding them in sections "content", "styles" and "scripts", respectively)**.

Comment: Are the css and js files quite large?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes, they are. The files are large and each view has several files so I think it's a bad idea to copy-paste the HTML lines that include these files in each page because they can be added or removed during the development process.

Comment: In that case I would suggest having a look at `stacks` and also `components and slots`. Also, if you're using the same css and js files in different pages then it might be an idea to use `mix` to combine and compress them. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#stacks https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

Comment: @RossWilson I didn't know about `stacks`. They seem very useful and maybe they could be a solution to my problem. I'll give them a try. Thank you very much!